# Box2d Ragdoll custom animation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, andengine

I have a ragdoll, completely controlled by physics, but I want to controll it by myself, adding an animation, and when I click on each part of the body, it acts completely physical

What I did was

1. Create the ragdoll completely with physics and joints
2. Be able to drag any part of it
3. Set state as animation and it changes the state of everybody to kinematic

What I want to do now is perform my animation to each part independently, I mean, change its position and its angle, problems:

1. When I rotate the arm and the legs, it rotates from the center, and I want it to rotate from the "joint point", so I can controll the arm angle with a simple setTransform(pos, angle)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually ragdolls are used when your character is killed to simulate it fall realistic. So i don't think you really need your character to be physical simulated all the time. More of this, if you will just set it's position you will get non-physical behavior anyway (you should at least have correct velocities for every part of your character, otherwise the simulation will not be realistic because of incorrect collision processing). So usually it's enough just to make an AABB or a bound sphere for controlling collisions with you character while moving. When the character dies - make a ragdoll to simulate the death. So i suggest you to separate graphical and physical representation of your character except death

Comment: Well i want to be able to drag the character and then act as a ragdoll so I thougt in having two states for the char, one walking with the body as kinematic and when i start dragging it set the body as dynamic. But i will have a lot of characters with a pool so creating the bodies when you start dragging it maybe is not a good idea..

Comment: And the other thing i want is to be able to set a part of the body to act physicaly like in zombie smash so this is the thing that made me decide to use the kinematic bodies so i can set one arm or a leg as dynamic

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol: Ok, you can then just make your body's shape in the way that the center of the body will be placed in the joint point. So the localAnchorA (or B) will be (0, 0)

Comment: And does it afect the mass center? And finally how do i apply the rotation? With the settransform?

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol. It will affect local coords of mass center, but not global since the shape actually will be the same. Try to control animation with set transform as it is the simplest solution. If it will not work possibly you can use joints motors to rotate parts ad dynamic bodies. The second way will give the best really physical behavior

Comment: Ok i think is a good solution so how do i set the body center? Imagine i have the torso body at 0,0 with 10 width an 30 heigth and i want the arm with 5 width an 30 heigt to be in the middle of the torso and the rotation point at 5,0 i tried defiñing the body shape with the overloaded method for setting the bodys origin and as dynamic it works but when i settransform it with the angle it rotates from the center of the shape again..

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol: If you are adding a shape like this: b2PolygonShape shape; shape.setAsBox(5, 5, 5, 5, 0); then it should rotate around the corner of the box. Try this please. And avoid using the same dimensions for physics as for graphics. Take a look at box2d manual and read about best dimensions

Comment: It didn't work, in fact I create the body like this: createBoxBody(m_PhysicsWorld, m_UpperArmLeftSprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, fixtureDef) so the dimensions are addapted automatically I think